# removing windows 7 after ubuntu installation

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

i intend to install ubuntu  14.04 into my toshiba c855d laptop, windows7,  with a dual boot option. i want ubuntu to sit side by side with windows7, not within it. then, at a later date, when i am skilled with ubuntu, i want to totally remove the windows7 OS and allow ubuntu to occupy my entire hard drive. is this possible? i know that during the ubuntu installation, i am given the option to remove windows7. but i want to do that at a later date. i will be using the downloaded installation disc i made from the ubuntu.com website.

thanks for your patience for this newcomer.

Answer (score 1):

[Os -uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller) is a small graphical tool to perform a clean and quick uninstall of any operating system (Windows, MacOS, Ubuntu, other Linux distribution..) of your computer.

- boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB.
- choose "Try Ubuntu"
- open a new Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), then type:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
- Press Enter

- then type:

sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -y os-uninstaller && os-uninstaller
- Press Enter

Using OS-Uninstaller
launch OS-Uninstaller (System->Administration->OS-Uninstaller menu if you use Gnome, or via the dash if you use Unity)

Then choose the OS you want to remove and click "OK"

http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1323945652.png

A confirmation window will appear:

http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1336577243.png

Click "Apply" to start the removal

Answer (score 0):

You can install windows and ubuntu on separate partitions. First create a separate partition for Ubuntu and swap (minimum size equal to your ram) while in windows7 after creating partitions reboot and boot with ubuntu live cd, start the installation and don't select option to remove windows7 select the "something else" option at the bottom then you can see the partition details select the partition you created for ubuntu and swap partition  go through page

http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/step-by-step-beginners-guide-to-installing-ubuntu-11-10.172128/

select the partitions carefully identify them based on the sizes if you install in wrong partitions you will lose data. so check in which partition you are installing twice.

I hope that helps